# running docker command from within a container

Tags: docker, containers

I am using the docker gdal image to run certain commands for example:

```
docker run --rm -v /storage/:/storage osgeo/gdal gdal_translate -stats -of GTiff input.tif output.tif
```

however, the code that is executing these commands is within another container itself, so running this command doesn't work since docker is not found:

```
 /bin/sh: 1: docker: not found
```

what can I do to resolve this? the gdal docker image is from another source

Comment: Have you tried installing docker in the container?

Comment: And by the way, you should also pass via bindmount the host dockerd unix socket so you don't need to run the docker daemon inside the container: i.e `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: @DanielWalker installing docker in container? is that a common way and does it work?

Comment: PS: You can also pass via bindmount a statically linked docker binary available in your host so you don't have to install docker in the container.

Comment: I don't know if it's common.  However, it's certainly possible.  You can install programs inside of a container.

Answer (score 1):

If you have available a [statically linked docker client binary](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/#install-static-binaries) on your host, you can:

```
$ docker run --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker \
    -v /storage/:/storage osgeo/gdal \
    gdal_translate -stats -of GTiff input.tif output.tif
```

This way you don't need to install docker in your container.

The other obvious option is to:

1. Install docker within your container using the available package manager (depends on the base image used for your container, i.e: [`apt-get`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/), [`yum`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/), etc)
2. Download the [pre-compiled binaries](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/#install-static-binaries) directly to your container
3. Rebuild the original Docker image with docker package already installed to save you the trouble.

As @emory pointed out, if you do not trust the docker image, sharing your Host Docker Daemon might become a security issue. If this is the case, create a [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create/) and proceed with sharing your docker-mahchine Docker Daemon with the container. This is indeed safer!

Comment: A slight variation on this is to use docker machine. https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/  to create another Docker host.  That way you do not have to share your Docker host with the container.  It sounds like OP has not personally vetted the container code and sharing your docker host is like giving sudo access.